# WYSIWYG Software for editing a Sharepoint Wiki as regular user: what software and what permissions do I need?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This is in an enterprise environment. I am trying to figure out a more   convenient way to edit a Wiki that I have created in Sharepoint.
I am totally new to this so forgive my naive questions if they are so:
-after circumventing the installation of sharepoint on my laptop (I ended up   installing it on my desktop) I created a wiki using the wiki application
 available to me in sharepoint but I am totally unhappy with the "easiness" of   of this app. I would like to use a WYSIWYG app and it seems that I need some
permissions in order to use Sharepoint Designer 2013.
Before going to the admins I wanted to ask here, what is the level of   permissions that I need to ask for in order to be able to use Sharepoint   Designer 2013 to create and edit the pages of my Wiki?

Is there an alternative to SD2013? I am under the impression that this is mostly desinged to manage Sharepoint. Maybe I am wrong and SP2013 is not the tool I should be looking for and I do not need to ask for any permissions I just need to use the right tool

Comment: In my opinion the implementation of Wiki in sharepoint sucks and it is not very friendly. What is the purpose of your wiki? I found actually using OneNote is much better for crating space where people can collaborate on content (I use it for Knowledge Base, Project  collaboration etc) just place one note in library that does't need checkout and multiple users can connect to it .

Comment: I think that OneNote lacks the version tracking of the document doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it doesn't have versioning.

Comment: So that rules out that option right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Designer 2013 isn't a WYSIWYG. In SPD2010 you could edit pages in a more WYSIWYG style being able to insert and position different elements however SPD2013 the page editor is a code view so doesn't serve as a WYSIWYG. 
You can view more information in this article http://blog.visualsp.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/.

SPD2013 is a really useful bit of kit I would suggest having but it won't serve this purpose.

Comment: Any idea what would be an alternative ? I used to work with FrontPage long time ago ..is there anything like this for Sharepoint?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any software I'm aware of and I could be wrong about this but I don't think there is a WYSIWYG for SharePoint anymore. FrontPage evolved into SPD and the various versions available. However as the official product for use with SP removed this I'm going to assume anything that would allow you to do this will no longer be compatible or cause issues within your sites. There is some information on layouts and design and how to edit these that may be of use to you. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint